# cakephp 3 get method not returning fields

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, get, cakephp-3.0

- CakePHP 3.5.
- PHP 7.2.8
- Docker env
- mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib
  10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

> 

```
CREATE TABLE `feedback_calls` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TENDER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MANAGER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TITLE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVENT_START` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVENT_END` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_ON` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCKED_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATED_ON` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATED_BY` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_Tender_idx` (`TENDER_ID`),
  KEY `FK_FeedbackCalls_User_idx` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Tender` FOREIGN KEY (`TENDER_ID`) REFERENCES `dls_tender` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_FeedbackCalls_User` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `dir_user` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQl table contains:

[image]

Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\Log\Log;
use Cake\Database\Type;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

final class FeedbackCallsTable extends Table
{

use VirtualFieldsTrait;

/**
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->setTable('feedback_calls');
    $this->setDisplayField('ID');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('ID');
}


public function index($id = null)
{
    $eventData = $this->get($id);
    log::debug($eventData);
}
}
```

When I use [cakephp 3 get method](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key) I get MANAGER_ID value as null.

```
log::debug("ID is ::".$id);
    $eventData = $this->get($id);
    log::debug("EventData is :: ");
    log::debug($eventData);
```

output:: [image]

Additional info: It is also not saving the field on update operation. I've cleared the cache tables and also tried to find method as well but got same results. Any solution/ advise is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: There is not need to add UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`). Primary key is itself unique. Can you please share $this code?

Comment: Good..keep on learning

Comment: As mentioned earlier, I have cleared cache and still had a issue. But when I set my debug to 2(earlier it was 1 ), it is returning the field value as expected. Not sure, if cakephp 3 caches the models elsewhere. Does anyone know?

Comment: Schemas are by default cashed in `tmp/cache/models`. This can be changed via the `_cake_model_` cache configuration, which is by default in `config/app.php`.